# Buffering multiple linestrings

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I'm pretty new to postgresql, so there might be a pretty simple answer to my question, at least I hope so.

I have imported a table with thousands of single linestrings that represent the main roads of a country.
I'd like to buffer every single one of them and intersect the results with another polygon (Basically just a circle, but the thing is, that the position of the circle is dynamic, depending on the preferences of the user).

However, I don't know how to buffer all linestrings at once. It works just fine when I buffer and intersect just one linestring, but it's kinda crucial that I buffer all of them.
And importing the roads as a multilinestring with SPIT doesn't work at all.

So ... how do I make that happen? Any hints?
I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you want to add a new field with the buffered linestrings or run a query intersecting a circle against a buffer each time. The 2nd approach will likely be very slow.

Comment: How did you buffer one linestring? It's usually easier to buffer a whole table without a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to simply add another column that represents the buffers of the roads and add a spatial index, ie,

```
alter table roads add column road_buffer geometry(POLYGON, SRID);
update table roads set road_buffer = st_buffer(roads, distance);
create index ix_spatial_road_buffer on roads using gist(road_buffer);
```

where POLYGON and SRID indicate the type and spatial reference ID of the column. You can omit this, although it is good practice to use a specific type and SRID. YOU could also use [AddGeometryColumn](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html) for the same end.

You can now run a query against the buffered roads, which will be fast, as it is indexed, but return the actual roads, eg,

```
Select road_id, road from roads where st_intersects(road_buffer, circle);
```

Now, if you wanted to do it the other way, without actually having a pre-buffered linestring, you could do somthing like,

```
select road_id, road, road_buffer from 
  (select st_buffer(road, dist) as road_buffer, road, road_id
    from roads where 
    st_intersects(st_expand(st_envelope(road), dist), circle)
  ) road_buff 
where st_intersects(road_buffer, circle);
```

The trick here is that you compute the buffer in a subquery, but only for those linestrings/roads whose envelope (ie, minimum bounding rectangle) intersects with your circle -- a much faster calculation than buffering all linestrings. Note, also, the use of st_expand, by the same amount as the buffer distance, which basically expands the mbr and ensures you don't miss any potential candidates. I did a quick test on half a million random lines, and this approach was much faster (10x) than simply checking for circle intersections against the  buffer of all points.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I came up with a solution that works just fine.
I just buffered my linestrings externally (used qgis) and reuploaded the entire thing as one big polygon.

However, I'd still like to know how it is done while maintaining the linestring structure.
Both approaches that John Barça suggested would work for me.

Comment: I have put both methods in an answer. I much prefer the first one, but the second one might work for you. As always, test for your setup and use cases.